# Developing an application that creates financial chart from web services

Tags: php, asp.net, web-services, architecture, scalability

I'm trying to create an application that will create a chart that will get the data by calling a financial web service. Users will interact with the chart by clicking on it. There could be millions of views on the application, so millions of requests on the web service. What's the best way to do this?  Will I need to call the web service each time, a million times?

Comment: You will improve your chance of getting the attention of someone who can help you if you add a tag for the programming language(s) you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it you would be better off reading the data from the web service at fixed interval (every X seconds/minutes/hours depending if your data is real-time or not) and displaying the graph with that information. That way your number of requests to the web service will not vary and you can change one part of the equation without affecting the other.

**Edit after first comment**: my answer stands. You would be better off getting the data at a fixed interval and inform users that the data is supplied with a delay (the usual delay with financial activity data is 15 minutes). That way you know in advance the number of requests you will run and you greatly speed up the service to your users.

**A word of warning**: Yahoo Finance changed its API licensing in 2012 or 2011 and it is now forbidden to use data from the API for public applications without a commercial license.

Comment: Sorry for the late response.  I will be using php and we will be talking to the yahoo finanical webservice api.